# Ask if you want record video or take photo

Tags: android, video, android-intent, photo

how can i make that when the user click in a button, this ask to take a photo or video with intent?

Actually i show an alertdialog with 2 buttons, but i know the are the posibility to show the tipical intent file ask, and select in there.

```
  @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tipo_fichero = "1";
                cuando = ANTES;
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "Selecciona una accion"),
                        CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
```

I try with this but this only open me the gallery

Comment: Can you be more clear, do you want to show a dilog which asks for "Ask if you want record video or take photo" & on click redirect them to corresponding page?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `Intent#createChooser` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser

Comment: But with this how can i combine take photo and record video? I think its not posible